# How do I use inoremap with multiple characters?

Tags: vim, vimrc, key-binding

I am new to ViM customization. I am almost done getting autocompletion to work as I would like. Here is the line of interest:

```
inoremap <expr> i (pumvisible() ? '' : 'i<C-n>') . '<Down>'
```

Notice that it captures i and then still types it (and then sends `<C-n>`). I would like for this to work like a regular expression. How can I get this to work with any word character? I'd rather not have several copies of this each for a different character.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are no wildcards in mappings; you'd have to create all those mappings with a loop:

```
for i in split('abcdefg...', '\zs')
    execute printf("inoremap <expr> %s (pumvisible() ? '' : '%s<C-n>') . '<Down>'", i, i)
endfor
```

Please note that there are plugins that achieve auto-completion as you type (what you seem to attempt here); I use [AutoComplPop - Automatically opens popup menu for completions](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1879)